# How to create an html form and embed it to an iframe?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create an HTML form and embed it to an iframe, so later on the frontend can access the iframe. I don't have a clear logic/idea how to do it and that's why I need help.

```js
router.get(`/iframeRendered`, (req, res) => {
  /*
    return HTML page and attach to iframe
  */

  res.send(`iframe here`)
});
```